# Is positively curved Alexandrov surface isometrically embeddable in $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I guess it is not. The example I have in mind is: $X^2$ is the spherical suspension of a circle $S^1(t)$ of length $0<t<2\pi$. Then $X$ has constant curvature =1 except at two suspension points, say $N$ and $S$.

But I cannot convince myself, since it seems this manifold can be approximated by a sequence of smooth Riemannian metrics $g_i$ with positive curvature by smoothing arbitrary small neighbourhood of $N$ and $S$, then by Pogorelov, if we assume sufficient smoothness on $g_i$, we get desired embedding by taking limit.

Comment: By Alexandrov realization theorem, proved in 1948, every nonnegatively curved $2$-sphere is isometric to the boundary of a convex body. Here "nonnegatively curved" is understood in the comparison sense. The proof strategy is to approximate a given metric by a nonnegatively curved polyhedron, embed the polyhedron, and then pass to a limit of such polyhedra. I suppose one can also smooth the metric, use the PDE method to find an isometric embedding and then pass to a limit but this is not what Alexandrov did because the relevant PDE methos came in later.

Comment: @Igor, Do you know any explicit embedding of the suspension $X$ in my post?

Comment: The suspension has an involution fixing the base and also has rotational symmetry. The embedding is unique up to a rigid motion. So the embedding must be given by a surface of revolution obtained by rotating a curve in the $xz$-plane about the $z$-axis, and then reflecting in the plane $z=0$. Find the curve yourself.

Comment: Thanks Igor, I found the expression. Just for reference, it is parametrized by $a(t)=r*\cos(t), b(t)=\int_0^t \sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2{s}}ds$, where the circle has length $2\pi r$ which is the $t$-parameter in O.P..

Comment: @IgorBelegradek re "relevant PDE methods", I strongly suggest reading Busemann's math review of Nirenberg's paper.

Comment: @IgorRivin: I am not sure what you are referring to. I think there is a PDE proof of the existence of an isometric embedding independent of "approximation by polyhedra method" at least if the metric is sufficiently smooth. This is all I said.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek You are, of course, correct, but you should look at the review for Busemann's opinion of Alexandrov's work vs the PDE methods (by the way, the latter ARE more suitable to regularity results).

Comment: @IgorRivin I read Busemann's review, it is really interesting. But I am confused by the 'mood' of your mood in the comments.

Comment: @JohnB Which 'mood' do you mean?

Comment: @IgorRivin: Regarding Busemann's review my impression is that Busemann did not go through details of Pogorelov's papers and just looked at the claims there. I have not read Pogorelov's regularity papers myself but I have heard it is a very hard going (especially the part where he proves regularity of the isometric embedding of a metric that is not sufficiently regular intrinsically). I recommend Borisenko's survey (which it seems only available in Russian at http://www.mathnet.ru/php/getFT.phtml?jrnid=jmag&paperid=33&what=fullt&option_lang=rus) for detailed account and proof sketches.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I agree that the regularity is the hard part. I asked Gromov once if anyone had read Pogorelov, and he said Reshetniak had read it carefully...